# Assign values to a slice struct in go ( golang )

Tags: go

How can I assign values to a var of type []struct ?

```
type Mappings []struct {
    PropA       string  
    PropB       string 
}

func main() {
    var test Mappings
    test = ???
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
type Mappings []struct {
    PropA       string  
    PropB       string 
}

func main() {
    var test Mappings
    test = Mappings{
        {PropA: "foo", PropB: "bar"},
        {PropA: "bar", PropB: "baz"},
    }
    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I wasted hours on this; it was the trailing comma getting me!

Comment: shorthand `test := Mappings{{"France", "Paris"}, {"Italy": "Rome"}}`

Comment: no that won't work, it would need to be `test := Mappings{{"France", "Paris"}, {"Italy": "Rome"},}`

Comment: @shazbot The trailing comma is only necessary if you're using a line break because Go will implicitly add a `;` (statement terminator) to the end of every line that doesn't end with certain tokens. See the ["Semicolons" section of the Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons)